# Abort request in Fiddler script automatically

Tags: fiddler

It is possible to run a script on `prerequest` and `preresponse` in Fiddler script. I want to automatically abort requests that contain a string in the URL.

In the Fiddler GUI it is possible to abort the request by right clicking the request and then clicking abort but I want to do this automatically.

In Fiddler script in the `onbeforerequet` method I have added

```
 if (oSession.uriContains("string")) {  
      //abort request   
  }
```

This is true when my string is contained in the URL. How can I abort the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
oSession.oRequest.FailSession(404, "Blocked", "Fiddler blocked request");
```

Should do the deal.

Comment: This is the best choice although it doesn't do exactly what Fiddler's "Abort" command does. The abort command kills the processing of the session by killing its thread, which works in more situations but is something to be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (bWantToDropConnection){
    oSession.oRequest.pipeClient.End();
    oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
    oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseCode = 0;
    oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "0 Client Connection Dropped by script";
    oSession.state = SessionStates.Aborted;
    return;
}
```

Credits go to EricLaw (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/Bf-DUuXbqfg)